# Calculate the table's contentSize.height with custom cells of different types iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application , the tableview is having different types of custom cells with different heights. I want to put a view below this tableView, for which I need to calculate the table contentView height, how can I do it?

Earlier I used to do it like: (noOfRows * cell_height), but that was for static heights.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 20):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, therefore you can use the instance method contentSize on your tableview:

```
yourtableView.contentSize.height
```

Should give you the height of your tableview content view

Comment: This returns 0 if you use custom cells with custom heights.
EDIT: This returns correct value if you call `TableView.ReloadData()` first. :)

Comment: This is not sufficient if the cells have dynamic height, as in they are the same type of cell, but their heights differ based on the size of their content

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but, today I've solved my problem with this

```
  func viewDidLoad() { 
      super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 //  >= 2
    }     

  func getTableViewHeight() -> CGFloat{ 
      tableView.reloadData()
      tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

      return tableView.contentSize.height + tableView.contentInset.bottom + tableView.contentInset.top
    }
```

Comment: `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` is the key!

Answer (score 5):

i have calc height in viewDidLayoutSubviews() for content view controller. Work for me (table view automatic cell dimensions);

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
    let height = table.contentSize.height+table.contentInset.bottom+table.contentInset.top
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 305, height: height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The header and footer of the section are not considered in the height of the table, consider this**

```
CGSize sz = self.table.contentSize;
sz.height += self.table.contentInset.bottom +
             self.table.contentInset.top + 
             self.table.numberOfSections * self.table.sectionHeaderHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of would be to set your view as the table's [tableFooterView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView)

Comment: Thanx chrispix.. but footerView doesn't helpme achieve my requirements. Basically, I'm trying to make pullToReload view under my tableview which should be placed below tableview, so that whenever ending content-offset of tableview contentview is visible, this should not be visible, whereas the footerView is visible at the ending offset of tableview contentview.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `self.view.bounds.size.height`.

Check out [Oliver Drobnik's detailed post on creating a pull-to-reload table view](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/). In his case it's easier, because the view is at the top, so he checks for a negative contentOffset.

If you want it at the bottom, you could check for `scrollView.contentOffset.y > (self.view.bounds.size.height + pullToReloadViewHeight)`

Answer (score -3):

If you've implemented your own custom cells, then you've probably already implemented this function in your table delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Just iterate through your rows, calling this function for each one, and sum up the result.

Comment: Doesn't include header size