# When to know UITableView's contentSize

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to add a subview to the bottom of my UITableView and in order to do so i need to know the table view's contentSize property. But i'm thinking about the best way to do so, i mean when, in which method; when i create the table view i still doesn't know how many cells is going to have.

So could i do it in numbersOfRowsInSections? Or would it be more appropriate to do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, asking the delegate if it is the last cell and adding it in that moment, only the first time.

If the tableView is simply added as a subview, viewWill/DidAppear are not going to get called, so none of them are a real choice.

**UPDATE**: I should clear out (as per first answers), that it must be below the table but in the table, not in the superView and don't want to use the footer, it must be a added subview. And i know how to get the contentSize, i'm asking myself where is the better place to handle it.

**UPDATE 2**: I've said it already, answering a comment below, but i think i also have to put it here because this is triggering down votes. I just don't care about a footer view. A footer view is not the question here, i don't want to use it and i've already found out how to add a subview manually. I'm just inquiring, as the title of the question saids, on what time, in what method, is it better to ask for the table view's contentSize.

Comment: i infer from your question that your tableview is added as a subview. So can u consider adding this view below the tableview as such?

Comment: Updated question regarding your answer

Comment: why don't you want to use the footer view?

Comment: Can you explain, why a footerView is not what you want?

Comment: Because i'm doing some things with scroll view properties that just doesn't work with a footer, it must be a custom view added as a subview to the table view. Again, i already know how to do it, i'm asking in what method would be better to get the contentSize.

Comment: so u should try to fix your code. using footerView results in an subview, only that the tableView performs the adding.

Comment: I don't understand why you said that. First, i need to do some calculations with contentSize, contentOffset, contentInset that doesn't work great/like i want to if i add the footer. Nevertheless, being that it might be my mistake, i'm just inquiring on what moment is appropriate to know a table view's contentSize. I don't care about the footer and as a matter of fact i do know how to add a subview manually. I'm just asking on what moment is better to ask for the contentSize.

Comment: there is no such a moment. A tableview calculates the content size by checking how you implemented the delegate. and as you and I don't know how this is done by the tableview, we cannot say, when to get it. maybe you can subclass UITableView and override methods like reloadData, but i discourage you to do so, as UITableView is not intended to be subclassed. If there is something wrong with scrolling and footer, it must me a error in your code. find and fix that error is the only useful advice that can be given.

Comment: Maybe instead of telling us, how you want to solve a problem, you should tell us, what problem it is.

Comment: Oh lord, there is no problem, i just wanted to know when was the best time to get the contentSize! My code is working (so you saying that it is impossible to know it is false), i just wanted to know if someone had any better idea as to WHEN TO ASK FOR THE CONTENTSIZE.

Comment: ok, let me repeat again: (a)assign a footerView IS the same as adding  (b) there is no moment to ask for a reliable hight.

Comment: Well, turns out there are two places, at least, to get a "reliable height" and i mentioned both of them in my question.

Comment: I can promise you: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowInSection:` are not places where you get reliable data. It may work in some simple cases, but you will see, it won't work always. pouting won't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the view you want to place at the bottom of your table to table's `tableFooterView` property.

Answer (score 2):

UITableView has a tableFooterView property http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I think setting this property with your view do exactly what you want

Comment: also check it out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231525/calculate-the-tables-contentsize-height-with-custom-cells-of-different-types-ip

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i want to do some calculations and things so the footerView is not what i need but a simple view added below, what i'm asking my self is where is the better way to know the contentSize.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(float)getTableViewHeight
{
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
return self.tableView.contentSize.height;
}
```

I think this is you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

//you can add your view in this method. with return key
//like
return view;

}
```

Comment: Updated my question, i don't want to use the footerView, it must be a added subview.

Comment: @KartikArora Note that you are adding a footer to a section, but tableViews also had a property footerView for adding a footer for the tableView itself.

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Get Througth The below Code

```
NSLog(@"%f",YourTableObject.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: Updated question regarding your answer

Comment: Then Write logic Accordingly If indexpath.row is last object Then do what ever you want in cell for row at index path

Comment: I said that in my question's second paragraph, do you think that's the better way to do it then? Thanks!