# Make UITableView's height depended on it's cells' height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got a table in my Swift project

```
tableView = UITableView()
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = UITableViewCell()
        let ProfilePicture = UIImageView()
        ProfilePicture.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cole")
        ProfilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        ProfilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let username  = UILabel()
        username.text = posters[indexPath.row]
        username.textColor = UIColor(r: 68, g: 68, b: 85)
        username.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 18)
        username.numberOfLines = 0

        let postText = UITextView()
        postText.text = postTexts[indexPath.row]
        postText.textColor = UIColor(r: 83, g: 92, b: 87)
        postText.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 15)
        postText.isScrollEnabled = false
        postText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        let border = UIView()
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 17, g: 221, b: 219)


        cell.addSubview(ProfilePicture)
        cell.addSubview(username)
        cell.addSubview(postText)
        cell.addSubview(border)

        ProfilePicture.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 14, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50,heightConstant:50)
        username.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom: postText.topAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 13, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0,heightConstant:20)
        postText.anchor(username.bottomAnchor, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom:nil, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0)
        border.anchor(postText.bottomAnchor, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: cell.bottomAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0,heightConstant:1)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.sizeToFit()
        return cell
    }
```

Cell's get automatic height,but `tableView`'s height is not automatic how can i make it automatic? I am not using storyboards only programmatical approach.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231525/calculate-the-tables-contentsize-height-with-custom-cells-of-different-types-ip

Comment: By implementing proper auto layout constraints you can achieve this

Comment: @karthikeyan it returns `estimatedRowHeight ` multiplied by the number of cells

Comment: yes, get height and adjust your table view frame.if you using auto layout, use constant.

Comment: @karthikeyan i updated it to `tableView.contentSize.height+tableView.contentInset.bottom+tableView.contentInset.top` here is the result http://imgur.com/a/Z2DxI

Answer (score 1):

You should use AutoLayout and make sure all components anchor to **top** and **bottom** of the contentView, like this:

[image]

Comment: I have done it,but when i leave tableView's heightConstant to 0 it doesn't show anything

Comment: Did you implement this method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {}`? If yes, let remove it.

Comment: I have removed it

Answer (score 0):

You can make dynamic cell which will be dependent on label's height using

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // in your viewDidLoad
```

but make sure that you are not giving fix height and width constraint to your label.

you should set numberOfLines = 0. With this your label will have multiline text.